# Как алгоритм RSA кодирует ключи в читаемый человеком вид?

Tags: php, rsa, криптография

Есть [пример класса на php](http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/4210), реализующего RSA шифрование. Он наглядно показывает как устроен алгоритм. Но не показывает самое интересное для меня, перевод ключей в стандартизированный формат вида

> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- MIIBVAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT4wggE6AgEAAkEAvw3LKlpU7pmiBwGb
>   YdiJp2XT9tq8OoZE2Rhvy72BdEN+pqpR4MCjxcHNXXkOychyuBoTSsI8yfHn/HIU
>   Yf/i5wIDAQABAkA2Evxex2Rkh91BKGZHIleLppmAs9Y0pk4UOANkYgWi1v5nrcMz
>   Cl0l3dlgUNNHgJVPHdxVyaPMH93S3eQHxrzZAiEA4lFOpEfKS9P3S1RRMep2RSTn
>   SSbxkMZ09hWKHiT4FF0CIQDYHH6Y19VJb6imaeZhm8sQ6fNve+/JJsFGmqhvnIng
>   EwIgJn9GLVO46aUoz7uMBD2p2KEqZpslREc95g5L7EzFllECIBXNqigZfndOQKGp
>   hYjLgw1NzTWuN17//ff1mpDIJlDpAiEAuV+pg0X6SBQLkdRBLx0FnOAluUo5XHxR
>   BY5lNGEWfDM=
>   -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

и

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAL8NyypaVO6ZogcBm2HYiadl0/bavDqG
>   RNkYb8u9gXRDfqaqUeDAo8XBzV15DsnIcrgaE0rCPMnx5/xyFGH/4ucCAwEAAQ==
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Есть ли какой-то стандарт/алгоритм форматирования, который описывает то как цифры превращаются в подобные строки?

**Как это делается в OpenSSL?**

**P.S.** ключи рабочие, сгенерированы стандартной библиотекой OpenSSL. [Рабочий пример](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-pkey-new.php#111769)

Моя задача - написать класс, который позволил бы сгенерировать ключи и зашифровать сообщение, а расшифровать его можно было бы классом OpenSSL или в любом приложении поддерживающем RSA шифрование. Это означало бы то, что я освоил алгоритм шифрования и написал класс придерживающийся стандарта

Comment: Эти строки - данные, закодированные в Base64

Comment: А под Base64 там ASN1 наверняка...

Comment: Только вслушайтесь как звучит: УЦ на PHP!

Comment: @AntonShchyrov какие данные? Сериализованный массив? Строчные `e` и `d` для каждого ключа соответственно? Или соедененные строки `en` и `ed`? Почему вы думаете что это Base64?

Comment: @TryCatch А почему вы думаете что это НЕ base64?

Comment: Это base64, формат сертификата называется PEM.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов в конечном счете не имеет значения base64 это или нет. Вопрос в том, какие данные там закодированы и как привести ключи к этому виду

Comment: @TryCatch openssl asn1parse покажет что именно там закодировано.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов спасибо, это так. Распарсил ключ из шапки [тут](http://lapo.it/asn1js), в [этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/181320/) говорится "Первое и третье числа — это номер версии и открытая экспонента e. Второе и четвертое числа — это модуль n и секретная экспонента d". Я правильно понимаю, что мне осталось лишь найти способ и закодировать  эти данные в ASN.1? Если да, то как именно это следует делать корректно? Я не о ASN.1, а о том в какой параметр что засовывать, наверняка где-то есть описание этого. Какое-то описание кодирования

Comment: @TryCatch посмотрите про X.509 и/или PKCS7